# Variable/parameter/function visibility OF a function within a function - SCOPE Question

Tags: javascript, function, scope, javascript-scope

I have been working on this for 3 hours exploring videos on scope, functions, function strings, and variable parameters. But I cannot get it right!

> **Quiz on Scope**
>
> Test your understanding of variable visibility.
>
> ```
> var outside = 'outside';
>
> function a() {
>   var aVar = 'a';
>
>   function aInner1() {
>     var aInner1Var = 'aInner1Var';
>
>     function aInner1Inner() {
>       var aInner1InnerVar = 'aInner1InnerVar'; 
>     }
>   }
>
>   function aInner2(aInner2Param) {
>     var aInner2Var = aInner2Param;
>   }
> }
>
> function b(bParam) {
>   console.log(bParam);
> }
> ```
>
> **Which of the following statements are true for the above code? Select 1 or more.**
>
> 1. a is visible to b
> 2. b and bParam are visible to a
> 3. aInner1InnerVar is only visible to aInner1Inner and aInner1
> 4. aInner1InnerVar is visible to aInner1Inner
> 5. aVar is visible to aInner2
> 6. aInner1Var is visible to aInner2
> 7. aInner2Param is visible to aInner1

**My thoughts so far**:

I know a local function can see the parent function, (basically anything above it). But I don't know if it can see only the function name. Or also the parameter/variable/etc. And I know all functions can see global variables.

my attempt to pseudocode

```
function one() {            // one can see oneA, oneB, oneAB, two
   function oneA() {        // oneA can see one, oneB  
       function oneB() {    // oneB can see one, oneA, oneB 
     }
   }
   function oneAB() {       // oneAB can see one, two
     }
}
function two() {            // two can see one
}
```

1. a is visible to b // global scope function

   - YES
2. b and bParam are visible to a // function name "a/b" yes, not sure for param

   - ?
3. aInner1InnerVar is only visible to aInner1Inner and aInner1
   // var in block visible to function and outer function

   - ?
4. aInner1InnerVar is visible to aInner1Inner // var in block visible to function

   - ?
5. aVar is visible to aInner2 // function can see var inside another function

   - NO
6. aInner1Var is visible to aInner2 // function can see var of funct within a funct

   - NO
7. aInner2Param is visible to aInner1

   - NO

Comment: "*I cannot get it right!*" - what are you getting? What is your proposed answer, and where in particular do you have problems choosing? Which parts do you understand, which not?

Comment: Just updated the question @Bergi thank you for the notes!

Comment: @Bergi I understand the idea of: Local /global/block scope. I know var has global access. But as far as assessing visibility of a function (question 1), visibility of parameters and variables within different levels of 3 functions within 1. I am very confused and having trouble finding a resource to consult that directly advises on this. I have checked functions/scope on MDN, W3Schools, and youtube, now here also. But I cannot move forward.

Comment: Please do not post a link to a painting of code or text! Quote the text itself, and format the code. You can edit your question to update it

Comment: @LuisFernando updated! Thank you for the notes, new to the community.

Comment: @Bergi I added a ton more of my thought process to the question. Let me know if you have any pointers it would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: It's not quite clear what it means for "a function" to "see" a variable (or, for a variable to be visible "to" a function). Does it refer to code in the function (at the top level of the function body, in particular) seeing the variable?

Comment: @Bergi the question is on variable visibility (scope) so for 1-7 it is asking if the "blank" is within the scope of "Blank". Assuming it means if it is visible/in scope/aka accessible. EX: #5. aVar is visible to aInner2 - is aVar within the scope of access/visibility of the function aInner2.

Comment: Btw, did you trying running the code? Add some `console.log` statements, or even better `debugger;` breakpoints, and call the functions.

Comment: @Bergi I have been trying that also. This is supposed to be a very simple entry level exercise but its been 5 hrs and I cannot move forward in the lesson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1 = yes - function a and b are in the same scope
- 4 = yes - the variable is in the body of the function / in scope
- 5 = yes - the variable is within the parent function
- 2, 3, 6, 7 = no